# Page data-url attribute is not respected

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I do a redirect from `/form` page to a `/thank-you` page (e.g. after successful form submission) I want the page url to change, so I add a "data-url" attribute like this:

```
<div id="page-thank" data-role="page" data-url="/thank-you"> ... </div>
```

The problem is that the URL of the page does **not always** change. In cases when it **doesn't** change the div of the page in the DOM look like this:

```
<div id="page-thank" data-role="page" data-url="/form" data-external-page="true"> ... </div>
```

Notice the `data-url` attribute has been changed (if you look at the response code, it is `/thank-you`) and `data-external-page` attribute has been added. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

`data-url` is more for internal use for jQuery Mobile. Why not just use `$.mobile.changePage` with the url of page id?